# JProfiler 8 Issue using temporary license

Tags: licensing, temporary, jprofiler

We, on rare occasion, have to borrow a temporary JProfiler license from our floating license server, to use on a machine that is going to be outside of our LAN.  this process used to work fine before we upgrade to use JProfiler 8 server.
Since we did the upgrade, my client said that he was unable to use the temporary license on JProfiler 8 client and JProfiler 6.2.3 client.
Here is the error message: "This license is for an earlier version of JProfiler".

My client said the process asks for 3 things:
Name: My client entered his name as he had done in the past
Company: He entered our company's name, with the first letter being upper case
License Key:  He entered the license key that I had copied out of the server for him.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the license server. The version 10.1.2 of the license server fixes this issue.